# Accessing variables from Imported PowerShell Module

Tags: powershell

I have a number of scripts where I want to use set of common variables so I created a file called CommonVariables.psm1 where I initialize the vars.  This file resides in the same folder as the scripts that need to use it.

At the beginning of the other scripts I execute these 2 lines of code in an attempt to import and use the variables found in CommonVariables.psm1.

```
$myHome = resolve-path (Split-Path -Parent $PSCommandPath)
Import-Module -Name (Join-Path $myHome -ChildPath "CommonVariables.psm1") -Verbose
```

That seems to import fine but the variables are not initialized in the calling script.

To test this I put a this code at the end of the CommonVariables.psm1

```
Write-Host ("1-" + $someVar)
```

The output is as expected where $someVar has the initialized value.

The a similar Write-Host statement in the script that imports the CommonVariables.psm1 file and $someVar is null.

How can I import the CommonVariables.psm1 file and then use the initialized variables within it?

Comment: I think I just need to prefix my variables with $Global:someVar.

Comment: You can use the `-Global` flag on `Import-Module`, but again what it sounds like you are doing would be better as a `.psd1` and `Import-PowerShellDataFile`

Comment: I also named the file from CommonVariables.psm1 to CommonVariable.ps1 then used Import-Module with the -Global flag